# inputParser without varargin

Tags: matlab

I would like to use inputParser on the function `f(a,b,c,d)`, where a is mandatory and b-d are optional. I would like to keep b-d named = not use `f(a, varargin)`, because that varargin doesn't tell you anything when you actually want to use the function. The simple `p.parse(a,b,c,d)` obviously does not work unless all 4 parameters are given.

The only way I know how to do it is to use `setDefaultValue(argname, value)`, and then use `p.parse(...)` for checks if needed. But is there a simple way to hack this using just inputParser (without tons of ifs)?

As a side question, there is no easy way to do named arguments like in C# in MATLAB, right? So I would have that `f(a,b,c,d)` and use as such. First argument is a, then b, then c ... But when the user wanted to call it like `f(a, 'd', 3, 'c', 2)`, he could. In this example, he would keep default b and use 3 for d and 2 for c. Without tons of work on my side of course - I know how to do it, writing my own parsing of the thing, but I would like a simpler solution (like other person's parsing :))

Comment: *"because that varargin doesn't tell you anything when you actually want to use the function"*. Write documentation then! Dont break MATLAB because you are lazy to write 10 lines of comments

Comment: @AnderBiguri I do write documentation, but I personally find it incredibly helpful to see parameters the function requires when I write the function name. So I try to offer the same to users of my code. Say myRectangle(center, height, width). Seeing name of the parameter is usually enough to know which one you should input and don't need to even open help or doc. Then in documentation all options, defaults etc would be listed, as well as exactly what the function does, examples etc.

Comment: MATLAB shows that. It will show `f(a,b,...)` and then a link to "more help"

Comment: @AnderBiguri When the function is defined as `f(a,varargin)` it will show as `f(a,...)`, which isn't as helpful - you require opening help to see the order of `b`, `c` and `d` (or `height` and `width` in the myRectangle example).
So I tend to use varargin when using name/value pairs mostly, or very rarely used optional parameters.

Comment: I assume MATLAB decided to do that because some of their functions can take a massive amount of optional parameters. Being able to show them in screen will block half your screen with that supposedly tiny yellow box. Thus, it shows what you *need* to use, all the optional, go to docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im going to give you an alternative answer: Don't be lazy, write docs.

If you do this:

```
function [out]= foo(a,b,c,d)
%FOO does foo things
%
% FOO(a,b) does very foo thins to a and b
%
% FOO(a,b,c) is quite foo-y on c also
%
% FOO(a,b,c,d) c and d are optional FOO things

if (nargin==3)
...
```

then if the user presses `F1` or types `help foo` they will get all the information in the comments.

---

To have users able to put inputs such as `foo(1,2,'d',5)` in my code, I use the following `"inputparser"` for optional parameters:

```
function [c,d]=parse_inputs(argin)
opts=     {'c','d'};
defaults=ones(length(opts),1);
% Check inputs
nVarargs = length(argin);
if mod(nVarargs,2)
    error('InvalidInput','Invalid number of inputs')
end

% check if option has been passed as input
for ii=1:2:nVarargs
    ind=find(ismember(opts,lower(argin{ii})));
    if ~isempty(ind)
        defaults(ind)=0;
    else
       error('InvalidInput',['Optional parameter "' argin{ii} '" does not exist' ]); 
    end
end

for ii=1:length(opts)
    opt=opts{ii};
    default=defaults(ii);
    % if one option is not default, then extrac value from input
    if default==0
        ind=double.empty(0,1);jj=1;
        while isempty(ind)
            ind=find(isequal(opt,lower(argin{jj})));
            jj=jj+1;
        end
         if isempty(ind)
            error('InvalidInput',['Optional parameter "' argin{jj} '" does not exist' ]); 
        end
        val=argin{jj};
    end

    switch opt
        case 'c': 
          if default;
             c=4;
          else
             c=val;
          end
     ...
     otherwise
            error('InvalidInput',['Invalid input name:', num2str(opt),'\n No such option in SART()']);
    end
end
```

Then The first thing I do inside foo is:

```
[c,d]=parse_inputs(varargin);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the question on how to handle varying number of inputs without `varargin` was answered well by [Ander Biguri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667351/7649907).

Regarding the second part of the question on how to parse inputs in pairs, here is my simplified **"input parser"**:

```
function parseVarargin( argin )
% Simplified function to parse varargin property-value pairs

% Read input arguments
if mod(numel(argin),2)
    error('Uneven number of inputs')
end
for i = 1 : 2 : numel(argin)-1
    if ~ischar(argin{i})
        error('Properties must be strings')
    end
    isValid = evalin('caller', sprintf('exist(''%s'',''var'')', argin{i}));
    if isValid && ~strcmp(argin{i},'MRX')
        assignin('caller', argin{i}, argin{i+1})
    else
        error(['Undefined property %s. ', ...
            'Please note case-sensitivity.'], argin{i});
    end
end
```

To use it, simply set the default variable values and the call `parseVarargin` on `varargin`:

```
function foo( a, varargin )
%FOO general description
%
% Usage:
%   foo(a)
%   foo(a, 'property-value-pairs')
% 
% Properties:
%   b : This ...
%   c : That ...

% Default property values
b = 1;
c = [];

% Read property-value paris
parseVarargin( varargin );

% Do other stuff
```